# Is it possible to order by Boolean, then String, then Date in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

The associated question referring to this being a duplicate answers some but not all of what I have asked here.

Additional details at the bottom.

I am retrieving a large collection from an API where items in the collection are structured as below

```
object: {
ID: string (GUID),
Category: string,
Active: boolean,
CreatedDate: date,
... other similar fields

}
```

I would like to be able to order this collection first by whether it is active or not,
then by the category, then by the created date of the object.

It is possible to have multiple items of the same Category hence needing the addional filter on date.

Currently returning from the API (.NET) I can use LINQ to do

```
OrderByDescending(x => x.Active)
      .ThenBy(x => x.Category)
      .ThenBy(x => CreatedDate)
```

however when I add a new item to the list I do not want to have to go back to the API to retrieve the whole list again when I have all of the details in the Website already.

Is it possible to do a similar sort in the Angular TypeScript?

Looking at the Angular docs and other pages, there is a sort function on Repeating fields in the Angular HTML, with the components I am using this is not suitable and I would need to be able to do this ordering in the TypeScript file.

Additionally with the sorting I would need to be able to sort the Active boolean descending to keep Active = true at the top of the list, and Category and Date sorting to be ascending.

-------Edit----------
I have now tried the below

list = list.sort(function(a,b){
return Number(a.active) - Number(b.active) || a.category.localeCompare(b.category) || new Date(a.createdDate) - new Date(b.createdDate)
});

The error appering seems to be related to the date comparison, any suggestions?